# Python: Plot line graph with real distance between x values

Tags: python, plot

I am a beginner at plotting charts in python. I want to plot a line chart with the following x and y values so that the distance between x values is real.

`x = [5,10,20,30,40,50,100,500,1000,10000]`

`y = [110,112,120,124,125,146,147,150,167,170]`

I want the distance between x values 1000 and 10000 to be 9000 and the distance between x values 5 and 10 to be 5
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure about the question, so is that what you want ?
[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsD0k.png)
if so, then the code is as simple as the following :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([5,10,20,30,40,50,100,500,1000,10000], [110,112,120,124,125,146,147,150,167,170])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response, but how to show exact x-values like 5, 10, 20, ... in the x-axis with the corresponding y values.

Comment: it is possible to do that with plt.xticks(xValues)

Comment: some thing that would give you a proper look in your case would be something like this import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [5,10,20,30,40,50,100,500,1000,10000]
y = [110,112,120,124,125,146,147,150,167,170]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1000))
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

Given the tight distribution of the 'early' values in the `x` list, you risk the plot looking something like this, where the tick labels overlap each other.

[image]

However, if this is what you want, here is the code:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot

data = []
layout = {}

data.append({'x': x, 'y': y})

layout['xaxis'] = {'tickmode': 'array', 'tickvals': x}

iplot({'data': data, 'layout': layout})
```

#### Suggestion:

You might consider converting the xaxis labels to a log scale, which will yield a plot similar to:

[image]

This can be done using the following code, which has intentionally been kept simple.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import iplot

# Convert xaxis values to log10 scale.
x_log = np.log10(x)

data = []
layout = {}

data.append({'x': x_log, 'y': y})

layout['xaxis'] = {'tickmode': 'array', 'tickvals': x_log}

iplot({'data': data, 'layout': layout})
```